# JavaScript libraries overview

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been using jQuery as well as other JavaScript libraries for a long time now. But I know that much has happened on the JavaScript scene. Does anyone know of a video or website with an overview / walkthrough of the most popular libraries at the moment ? (What are they, strength, weaknesses)

Comment: Here is a good article: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2012/08/01/rich-javascript-applications-the-seven-frameworks-throne-of-js-2012/

Comment: You mean like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at these resources, they placed the main Javascript libraries

1. http://jster.net/
2. http://jamjs.org/